# Iterated TextArea in HTML which is changed and empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of TextArea loop by forEach of JSTL, just like this:

```
<c:forEach var="test" items="${data}">
   <td><textarea class="no-resize" name="submit-${test}"></textarea></td>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to know which TextArea is changed and if it empty when a button is clicked using JQuery

The button is just like this

```
<button class="btn " type="submit" form="controller" name="save" value="save" id="save" onClick="return onSave()">Save</button>
```

Here's what i tried so far:

```
function onSave()
        {
             $('.no-resize1').each(function(){
                 $(this).change(function(){
                    if(!$(this).val() == ''){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false; 
                    }
                 });
             });

        };
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your button should be this:

```
<button class="btn " type="submit" form="controller" name="save" value="save" id="save" onClick="onSave">Save</button>
```

Second, .change() binds the function specified so that each time that DOM node fires a change event, the function you specify will change.  This may be what you need:

```
function onSave() {
    $('.no-resize1').each(function(){
       if(!$(this).val() == ''){
           return true;
       }
    });
    return false;
};
```

This function iterates through all the DOM nodes with class .no-resize1 and will return false if all of the text areas are empty and true otherwise.

Comment: I need to know which textarea is not filled, I iterated the textarea with some other field, so i want to stop the submission if a specific field of the row is blank (for this case it's the textarea).

Comment: in the if statement, return $(this) instead of true.